# Why don't electrons build up opposite electric field in a semiconductor diode in open switch mode?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I understand that during the closed switch mode the opposite electric field gets wider, but i don't see the reason when in open switch mode when electrons beat the opposite p-n field (0,3-0,8 volts), the electrons will flow to the p direction, but there are also holes, that could bound the electrons, so the electric filed should getting larger.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your thought process here. Yes, electrons from the n-side flow into the depletion region. Holes do as well from the p-side. And, in the depletion layer they recombine and poof! they are gone.

Comment: I thought that why dont  build in the p - type semi conductor those electrons, that comes from the n type during the open side current? While those electrons who come from the opposite direction build in the p type semiconductor and thus close the current because they build a potencial gate.

Comment: Why would either electrons or holes ‘build up’ when detailed balance (generation and recombination) is in action?

Comment: i think that recombinating electrons could get in those holes that are caused from (for example) Bor atoms, because during the p-n current that cant happen the electrons get in those holes,